# Fetching data from zookeeper znode

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn, apache-zookeeper

I tried to get the data from zookeeper's znode using Java API. Followed below link

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zookeeper/zookeeper_api.htm
Program: ZKGetData.java

I'm getting results like this

> "(clusterSecondarynn1node4.test.com �>(�>)"

How to get "node4.test.com" alone.

Answer (score 0):

It is **strongly** recommended to use some layer against ZK, like Apache Curator, or ZkClient.
Here's an example

```
CuratorFramework zkClient = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder().connectString("localhost:2181").build();
zkClient.start();
boolean isExist = zkClient.checkExists().forPath("/myNode") != null;
if (isExist) {
    byte[] myNodeBytes = zkClient.getData().forPath("/myNode");
    if (myNodeBytes != null && myNodeBytes.length > 0) {
        System.out.println(new String(myNodeBytes));
    }
}
else {
    zkClient.create().withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT).forPath("/myNode", "foo".getBytes());
}
```